# Internal Server Error after upgrading module in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

After i clicked the upgrade option from Apps for my particular module, i was logged out and can see only the database selector page now. If I select my database, It gives me

**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

I think there is something wrong with my last code, But have no idea where or how do i fix this and login again .Here is the traceback,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'bio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 424, in load_modules
    registry.setup_models(cr)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 267, in setup_models
    model._setup_fields()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2609, in _setup_fields
    field.setup_full(self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 482, in setup_full
    self._setup_regular_full(model)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 2389, in _setup_regular_full
    invf = comodel._fields[self.inverse_name]
KeyError: 'id  '
2019-06-10 06:07:46,066 3151 INFO bio werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 06:07:46] "GET /web?db=bio HTTP/1.1" 500 - 11 0.014 0.340
2019-06-10 06:07:46,073 3151 ERROR bio werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'bio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 291, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 409, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 128, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1318, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1291, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 227, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1469, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 98, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 62, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 424, in load_modules
    registry.setup_models(cr)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 267, in setup_models
    model._setup_fields()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2609, in _setup_fields
    field.setup_full(self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 482, in setup_full
    self._setup_regular_full(model)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 2389, in _setup_regular_full
    invf = comodel._fields[self.inverse_name]
KeyError: 'id  ' - - -
```

I am using Odoo 12 CE. How do i fix this?

**EDIT**
Here is the mdoel in the module which i was trying to upgrade(Last change i made).

```
class proddetail(models.Model):
    _name = 'vendr.proddetail'

    name = models.Char(related='rel_product_template.name')
    numb = models.Char(string='No')
    area = models.Char(string='Area')
    production = models.Char(string='Production')
    prev_yr = models.Char(string='Previous Year')
    curr_yr = models.Char(string='Current Year')
```

Comment: Fixed the error after several hours of searching!. I had accidently put a whitespace in a one2many model field in another module. Strange, the error never gave a clue about that module!.

Comment: The error messages aren't helpful all the time. Welcome to Odoo programming or i bet to programming at all ;-) Could you please add the wrong code to your question (little understandable example with both models because it's a onetomany relation)? And you can answer yourself, which will help others with similar problems.

Comment: @CZoellner. Ok i've updated the question and given what went wrong in the answer.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after going through my modules a couple of hours, found that there was a single whitespace i accidently put.Removing it solved the issue!

the line with error:

```
samplet = fields.One2many('tests.sampletest','id ',string="Sample test details")
```

there is a whitespace immediately after id. The tests.sampletest is another model in the same module(not the one i was trying to update).